# Subscriber error in ROS

Tags: boost, geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is my subscriber declaration followed by the callback function

> message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Point32>
> point_sub(*nh, "tracked_point", 1);
> point_sub.registerCallback(&visualservoing3D::pointCallback);

The callback declaration is

> void
> visualservoing3D::pointCallback(const
> geometry_msgs::Point32ConstPtr& msg) {
> //Some functions }

But the following error pops up. I know its something to do with my subscriber.

> /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:225:
> error: no match for call to
> ‘(boost::*mfi::mf1<void,
> visualservoing3D, const
> boost::shared_ptr<const
> geometry_msgs::Point32*std::allocator<void
>
> > > &>) (const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Point32_std::allocator<void
> > > &)’

Thanks,
Nagsaver

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174083/subscriber-error-in-ros/) by [Nagsaver](https://answers.ros.org/users/18316/nagsaver/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-06-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) on 2014-06-19**:
It might be due to your subscriber having point32 rather than Point32.

**Comment by [Nagsaver](https://answers.ros.org/users/18316/nagsaver/) on 2014-06-19**:
It is capital P in the code. Dont know how it changed in my question. Everywhere I have Point32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your callback function is a class member of the class visualservoing3D. Using a class member as callback function is not the same as using a normal function.

You have to provide the class member of the class and the object.
See this example: http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Class_Methods

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1